# Entity Framework 4.3 CF selecting all records in many - to - many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, select, entity-framework-4, lambda

How to select all records from one table that have corespondent keys with other, using joining table. I have table dbo.Patients and dbo.Hospitals and dbo.PatientHospitals which has Primary keys from both tables. I need all recods from dbo.Patients that are in dbo.Hospitals, that is that are in joining table dbo.PatientHospitals, something like:

```
var currentHospital = db.Hospitals.Single(x => x.User_Id == UserID);

var model = db.Patients.Include("Hospitals")
              .Select(x => x.Hospitals == currentHospital);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code first, you do not need additional table for simple many-to-many relationship. You could define your entities like this

```
public class Patient
{
    ...    
    public virtual ICollection<Hospital> Hospitals { get; set; }    
    ...
}

public class Hospital
{
    ...    
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }    
    ...
}
```

And then you could just write `currentHospital.Patients`

Comment: I have my entities like this, and CF does generate third table on his own, my question is how to select all records from one that belong to another, something like, all patients from one hospital.

Comment: yes I do, and thanks. My point of view was, select all patients that belong to specific hospital, but the logic was, select hospital and all of hers patients, thanks, solved it!

Comment: var model = currentHospital.Patients.ToList();